# Why does my assembly code not work? It should open, write to and read a file on Linux x86_64

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I wrote a simple assembly program with NASM in Intel Syntax on Linux 64-bit. It's supposed to open, write to and read the file and to print its content on a terminal.

My Code:

```
%include "../linux/linux64.inc"

section .data
    filename:       db          "test.txt", 0x0
    msg:            db          "Hello, world!", 0xA
    msg_len:        equ         $-msg

section .bss
    content:        resb        128
    handle:         resb        8

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov     rax, SYS_OPEN
    mov     rdi, filename
    mov     rsi, O_CREAT + O_RDWR
    mov     rdx, 0644o
    syscall

    mov     [handle], rax

    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi, [handle]
    mov     rsi, msg
    mov     rdx, msg_len
    syscall

    mov     rax, SYS_READ
    mov     rdi, [handle]
    mov     rsi, content
    mov     rdx, 128
    syscall

    mov     rax, SYS_CLOSE
    mov     rdi, [handle]
    syscall

    mov     rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi, STDOUT
    mov     rsi, content
    mov     rdx, 128
    syscall

    mov     rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Furthermore there are some constants in linux64.inc

```
SYS_READ        equ         0
SYS_WRITE       equ         1
SYS_OPEN        equ         2
SYS_EXIT        equ         60
SYS_CLOSE       equ         3
STDIN           equ         0
STDOUT          equ         1
STDERR          equ         2
O_RDONLY        equ         0
O_WRONLY        equ         1
O_RDWR          equ         2
O_CREAT         equ         0100
O_TRUNC         equ         01000
O_APPEND        equ         02000
```

It's currently able to create the file and write to it but it seems that it's not able to read it

Comment: When you try to read the file, there is nothing written in it at the point you try to read.
You should rewind (`lseek` to begin) the file to see what you have written.

Comment: It works thanks. I was so stupid to forgot it XD

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that I forgot to set the file pointer back to the beginning of the file.

I added some constants to linux64.inc:

```
SYS_LSEEK       equ         8
SEEK_SET        equ         0
SEEK_CUR        equ         1
SEEK_END        equ         2
```

Then I modified my program and added following lines after writing to the file:

```
mov     rax, SYS_LSEEK
mov     rdi, [handle]
mov     rsi, 0
mov     rdx, SEEK_SET
syscall
```

That was the solution

Comment: Another alternative is to use a `pread` system call (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html) that takes a read-position as another argument, instead of a separate `lseek` system call.  As always, `strace` is highly useful for debugging, and in modern Linux, `grep . /proc/$(pidof a.out)/fdinfo/*` will show you the file position and flags of all your file descriptors.  (Useful while your program is stopped at a breakpoint in a debugger.)