# assembly store text into an external file

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, att

How to write data into an external file on Linux?

For instance, if I start the code with `.include "output.s"` and want to write "1111 0000" into it, then how to do this.

Comment: `.include` seems like an assemble time directive. Assemblers generally don't support writing anything (except the output file) at assemble time. Perhaps you are mixing up build time inclusion with run time file access.

Comment: Then how to store text into an external file using assembly?

Comment: Or do you mean that it is not possible to write anything to an external file using assembly?

Comment: Do you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312290/how-to-open-a-file-in-assembler-and-modify-it

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?  Are you programming with the libc?

Comment: Operating system is linux (ubuntu if it matters), and I am programming with libc

Comment: @User Then open write and close files the same way you would do it in C, i.e. by calling `open`, `write`, and `close`.  If you like, I can write an example for you.

Comment: An example would be nice.

Comment: [read and write to file assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37940707) has a 32-bit Linux example of making `open` and `read`/`write` system calls.  But it also starts off with a high-level overview of what to do, which you could do with x86-64 call numbers / calling convention for `syscall`.

Comment: Some existing Q&As that use NASM syntax include: [How to append to a file using x86-64 Linux system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48541868) / [Why does my assembly code not work? It should open, write to and read a file on Linux x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62510576). And a GAS Q&A:  [How to rewrite a files content? Linux x86\_64, assembly, GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53125140)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do file I/O is to use the libc.  Envision how you would do it in C, then do the same thing in assembly.  For example, in C you could do

```
int main() {
    ssize_t n;
    int fd;
    char buf[9] = "1111 0000";

    fd = creat("output.s", 0666);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("output.s");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    n = write(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
    if (n == -1) {
        perror("output.s");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(fd);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Next, translate the code step by step into assembly:

```
        .data
name:   .string "output.s"              # the file name
buf:    .ascii  "1111 0000"
buflen=         .-buf                   # the length of buf

        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function

main:   push    %rbx                    # free rbx and align stack

        lea     name(%rip), %rdi        # file name
        mov     $0666, %esi             # initial permissions
        call    creat                   # create the file
        cmp     $-1, %eax               # was the call successful?
        je      .Lfail                  # if not, process error

        mov     %eax, %ebx              # stash a copy of the file descriptor
        mov     %eax, %edi              # file descriptor
        lea     buf(%rip), %rsi         # buffer
        mov     $buflen, %edx           # buffer length
        call    write                   # write data
        cmp     $-1, %rax               # was the call successful?
        je      .Lfail                  # if not, process error

        mov     %ebx, %edi              # file descriptor
        call    close                   # close the file

        xor     %eax, %eax              # return EXIT_SUCCESS
        pop     %rbx                    # restore %rbx
        ret

.Lfail: lea     name(%rip), %rdi        # the file name
        call    perror                  # print an error message

        mov     $1, %eax                # return EXIT_FAILURE
        pop     %rbx                    # restore %rbx
        ret

        .size   main, .-main
```